# HTML5 / JS Linear Gauge

Tags: javascript, html, charts

I would like to display a linear gauge like the one in [fusion charts](http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/Contents/Widget_XML_API/Linear_Config.html) using html5 or javascript. On doing a google search i could not find any open source / free linear gauge similar to the one fusion charts have

Comment: You didn't find anything interesting here: http://webdesignledger.com/resources/13-useful-javascript-solutions-for-charts-and-graphs? or better [gauge.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/gauge/)

Comment: @JMax thanks for pointing to gauge.js. My question is not similar to the one you have pointed out as I am on the lookout for a linear gauge like in gauge.js

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve almost the same with http://amcharts.com, here is the code:

```
       <script type="text/javascript">
        var chart;

        var chartData = [{
            category: "",
            bad: 75,
            moderate: 15,
            good: 10
        }];

        AmCharts.ready(function () {
            // SERIALL CHART
            chart = new AmCharts.AmSerialChart();
            chart.dataProvider = chartData;
            chart.categoryField = "category";
            chart.rotate = true;
            chart.columnWidth = 1;

            // AXES
            // Category
            var categoryAxis = chart.categoryAxis;
            categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
            categoryAxis.gridPosition = "start";

            // value                      
            var valueAxis = new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
            valueAxis.stackType = "100%";
            valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
            valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
            valueAxis.gridCount = 20;
            valueAxis.axisAlpha = 1;
            chart.addValueAxis(valueAxis);

            // GRAPHS
            // firstgraph 
            var graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.labelText = "Bad";
            graph.valueField = "bad";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.fillColors = ["#d05c4f", "#ffb2a8"];
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // second graph                              
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.labelText = "[[value]]";
            graph.valueField = "namerica";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.lineColor = "#D8E0BD";
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // thirdt graph              
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.labelText = "Moderate";
            graph.valueField = "moderate";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.fillColors = ["#cba01e", "#fee3a0"];
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // fourth graph 
            graph = new AmCharts.AmGraph();
            graph.labelText = "Good";
            graph.valueField = "good";
            graph.type = "column";
            graph.lineAlpha = 0;
            graph.fillAlphas = 1;
            graph.fillColors = ["#74960c","#d2e594"];
            chart.addGraph(graph);

            // WRITE
            chart.write("chartdiv");
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="chartdiv" style="width: 500px; height: 100px;"></div>
</body>
```

And here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please be sure to read the [FAQ on Self-Promotion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#promotion) carefully. Also note that it is *required* that you post a disclaimer every time you link to your own site/product.

Comment: @zeroin I can't seem to get mine to work on JSFiddle. Can you post a JSFiddle of it? It would really help me. Thank you!

Comment: @zeroin i have managed to implement this onto my page however i dont understand they values in the little pointers and how they work? How can i get this to just display a single pointer in a certain position, say at 80 in the moderate section?

Comment: @zeroin If you'd be willing to update this for Amcharts 4/5, there's a bounty here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72889402/linear-gauge-functionality-via-amchart-4