# Linear Gauge functionality via AmChart 4

Tags: javascript, amcharts, amcharts4

I'm looking to do a chart like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11608947/html5-js-linear-gauge) using amcharts 4.

The question linked only supports AmCharts 3, and AmCharts 4 has no `.addGraph()` functionality. Is it possible to do this using XYCharts()?

```
const chart = new am4core.create(chartDiv.current, am4charts.XYChart);
chart.dataProvider = chartData;
chart.categoryField = 'category';
chart.rotate = true;
chart.columnWidth = 1;

// AXES
// Category
const categoryAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
categoryAxis.axisAlpha = 0;
categoryAxis.gridPosition = 'start';

// value
const valueAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
valueAxis.stackType = '100%';
valueAxis.gridAlpha = 0;
valueAxis.autoGridCount = false;
valueAxis.gridCount = 20;
valueAxis.axisAlpha = 1;

// GRAPHS
// firstgraph
const graph = new am4charts.XYChart();
graph.labelText = 'Bad';
graph.valueField = 'bad';
graph.type = 'column';
graph.lineAlpha = 0;
graph.fillAlphas = 1;
graph.fillColors = ['#d05c4f', '#ffb2a8'];
chart.createChild(graph);
```

I tried `chart.createChild()`, but that appears to be for containers like rectangles. How would I achieve the same functionality using AmCharts 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A gauge chart is essentially a stacked column(bar) chart of only 1 type of series data. I've modified stacked column chart to look like the gauge chart linked in the question.

working demo: https://codepen.io/rabelais88/pen/RwMGxxJ

```html
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/core.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/charts.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.amcharts.com/lib/4/themes/animated.js"></script>
<div id="chartdiv"></div>
<style>
#chartdiv {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
}
</style>
```

```js
// Themes begin
am4core.useTheme(am4themes_animated);
// Themes end

// Create chart instance
var chart = am4core.create("chartdiv", am4charts.XYChart);

// Add data
chart.data = [
  {
    type: "gauge",
    bad: 2,
    good: 7,
    worst: 1
  }
];

// Create axes
var categoryAxis = chart.yAxes.push(new am4charts.CategoryAxis());
categoryAxis.dataFields.category = "type";
categoryAxis.renderer.grid.template.location = 0;
categoryAxis.renderer.minGridDistance = 20;
// forcefully expand axis to make it look like gauge
categoryAxis.renderer.cellStartLocation = -0.12;
categoryAxis.renderer.cellEndLocation = 1.12;
categoryAxis.visible = false;

var valueAxis = chart.xAxes.push(new am4charts.ValueAxis());
// remove inner margins by syncing its start and end with min and max
valueAxis.min = 0;
valueAxis.max = 10;

// Create series
function createSeries(field, name, stacked) {
  var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
  series.dataFields.valueX = field;
  series.dataFields.categoryY = "type";
  series.name = name;
  series.columns.template.tooltipText = "{name}: [bold]{valueX[/]}";
  series.stacked = stacked;
  // add inner text
  const bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
  bullet.label.text = "{name}";
  bullet.locationX = 0.5;
}

createSeries("good", "Good", false); // base of stacked column
createSeries("bad", "Bad", true);
createSeries("worst", "Worst", true);

// Add legend
chart.legend = new am4charts.Legend();
```

## Edit

I've added hand as requested.

- added another a column and designated it as a non-cluster to make it ignore the grid layout.
- set the column's interaction and style as hidden and attached a bullet shape that looks like a 'clock hand'.
- it includes a lot of manual position manipulation; due to the limit of a pre-made charts.

On a side note, normally if a chart has anything unusual element, it's better to implement it with D3.js by scratch; fiddling with a pre-made chart will bring too much side effects later.

```js
// adding a pointing hand(clock hand) as annotation
// draw pointing hand
var series = chart.series.push(new am4charts.ColumnSeries());
series.dataFields.valueX = "current";
series.dataFields.categoryY = "type";
series.fillOpacity = 0;
// hide shape
series.stroke = am4core.color("rgba(0,0,0,0)");
// make it ignore other columns
series.clustered = false;
// disable tooltips
series.interactionsEnabled = false;
const bullet = series.bullets.push(new am4core.Triangle());
bullet.width = 30;
bullet.height = 30;
bullet.fill = am4core.color("black");
bullet.horizontalCenter = "middle";
bullet.verticalCenter = "top";
bullet.rotation = 180;
// manually change its position
bullet.dy = -65;

const label = series.bullets.push(new am4charts.LabelBullet());
label.label.text = "current: {valueX}";
label.label.dy = -30;
```

updated working demo with pointing hand(clock hand): https://codepen.io/rabelais88/pen/mdxOyYQ

[image]

Comment: Do you know if it's possible to get a clock hand, like http://docs.fusioncharts.com/flex/charts/Contents/Widget_XML_API/Linear_Config.html ?

Comment: @Blue I've added the clock hand. as requested. enjoy 